# Interface mismatch in dummy procedure Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90, mismatch

I got this error in Fortan 90:

> Interface mismatch in dummy procedure 'dfpmin' at (1): Shape mismatch in dimension 1 of argument n

My main code starts as:

```
program main
real(8), allocatable :: theta(:)
real(8), allocatable :: grad(:)
real(8), allocatable :: mat(:,:)
real(8), allocatable :: thetagrad(:)
```

and later in the code the vector `theta` is allocated to be of dimension `ntheta`

```
allocate(theta(ntheta))        
end program main
```

on the other hand the subroutine starts as

```
SUBROUTINE dfpmin(theta,n,gtol,func)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL(8), INTENT(IN)    :: gtol
    INTEGER, INTENT(IN)    :: n         ! number of elements in the parameter vector
    REAL(8), INTENT(INOUT) :: theta(n)  ! parameter vector over which you which to maximize
    INTERFACE                           ! This lets the subroutine know that func is not a variable, it is a function
        REAL(8) FUNCTION func(theta,n)   ! This is not the likelihood itself, it just let the program know
        IMPLICIT NONE         
        INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: n
        REAL(8), INTENT(IN) :: theta(n)
        END FUNCTION func
    END INTERFACE
END SUBROUTINE DFPMIN
```

Then I have this error of the dimensions over and over. I tried to change to `dimension(:)` in the subroutine, but it does not work.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: How do you call the subroutine `dfpmin`?

Comment: it is called, after given values to theta and ntheta as call dfpmin(theta,ntheta,1.0D-6,LOGLIKELIHOOD)

Comment: I' m wondering why the compiler says "interface mismatch in _dummy_ procedure 'dfpmin' at (1)", even if dfpmin is not dummy (or is it actually passed to another routine..?). Also wondering how LOGLIKELIHOOD() is actually defined/called.

Comment: likelihood is defined as follows

Comment: MODULE LIKELIHOOD
  IMPLICIT NONE
CONTAINS 
  REAL(8) FUNCTION LOGLIKELIHOOD(theta,ntheta)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    INTEGER, INTENT(INOUT) :: ntheta
    REAL(8), INTENT(IN) :: theta(ntheta)
    REAL(8), PARAMETER :: small=1.0d-250
    REAL(8) :: elapsed_time,prob(nind),p_dirich(5),aux,temp
    INTEGER :: j,time_in,time_out,time_rate,i,t,c,m
    call getpar(ntheta,theta)     

    DO i = 1, nind
  prob(i) = density(i)
  IF (prob(i)<small) prob(i)=small
    END DO
        LOGLIKELIHOOD = -SUM(DLOG(PROB))
  END FUNCTION LOGLIKELIHOOD
END MODULE LIKELIHOOD

Comment: main calls dfpmin, dfpmin calls the likelihood function... that sum like_aux for each individual... dfpmin is part of a minimization module that contains more subroutines that uses the same theta and n values...

Comment: Now the error is Error: Interface mismatch in dummy procedure 'func' at (1): INTENT mismatch in argument 'n'

Comment: @knary You can modify (edit) your original Question by pressing the "edit" button above (shown in grey), so could you update your original Question above with as much information as possible as written in your new comments? It should be really helpful to understand the whole picture.

Comment: "INTENT mismatch in argument n" probably comes from that ntheta in LOGLIKELIHOOD() has INTENT(INOUT), while the interface of func() in dfpmin() has INTENT(IN).